# SQL aggregating based on dimensions from table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, aggregation

Using SQL Server 2008.

I have a table of grouped dimensions like the following

```
Group | Dim1 | Dim2 | ...
1        1      A
1        1      B
2        1      B
3        NULL   C
4        2      NULL
```

I Then have a fact table like

```
Amount | Dim1 | Dim2 | ...
 100      1      A
 280      2      NULL
 130      1      NULL
 170      1      C
```

I would like to aggregate the Amount in the fact table based on the groups of dimensions in the group table. Using GROUP BY CUBE it generates way to many rows for dimension combinations i don't need.

Expected result set would be like

```
Amount | Group | Dim1 | Dim2 | ...
 300       1      1      A
 200       1      1      B
 400       2      1      B
1000       3      NULL   C
 100       4      2      NULL
```

Where amount is aggregated from the fact table.
[SQL Fiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6cfd7/1/0) to example showing the GROUP BY CUBE result set that i want to restrict to only the groups of dimesnion values in the DimGroups table in the example.

Comment: Would you show your select statement?

Comment: Please provide the **expected result** based in your sample data.

Comment: Create a demo in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join the result of the cube onto the `DimGroup` table.
There are two problems. It's fairly simple to deal with joining on nulls. It's slightly harder to deal with the multiple meanings of null. Fortunately there's a `Grouping` function that can distinguish between an underlying null value and a null added by the cube.

This answer assumes that when you have a null in the DimGroup that you want the cube meaning - i.e. the aggregate over any underlying value.

```
Select
    d.GroupId,
    d.Dim1,
    d.Dim2,
    d.Dim3,
    total
From (
    Select
        sum(Amount) total,
        Dim1,
        Dim2,
        Dim3
    From
        FactTable
    Group By
        Cube(Dim1,Dim2,Dim3)
    Having -- exclude underlying values with unknown (null) dims
        (Dim1 Is Not Null or Grouping(Dim1) != 0) And
        (Dim2 Is Not Null or Grouping(Dim2) != 0) And
        (Dim3 Is Not Null or Grouping(Dim3) != 0)
    ) c
        inner join
    DimGroups d
        on (c.Dim1 = d.Dim1 Or (c.Dim1 Is Null and d.Dim1 Is Null)) And
           (c.Dim2 = d.Dim2 Or (c.Dim2 Is Null and d.Dim2 Is Null)) And
           (c.Dim3 = d.Dim3 Or (c.Dim3 Is Null and d.Dim3 Is Null))
```

**<kbd>[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6cfd7/10)</kbd>**

Comment: Sort of yes actually a GROUP BY CUBE, but im only interested in certain combinations. Defined by my DimGroup table.

Comment: @Jepa I forgot SQL Server has a way to distinguish nulls in the underlying data from nulls in the cube. Updated answer.

Comment: Yes im currently using GROUPING_ID() function. It works thank you. Will it scale as the subquery result from GROUP BY CUBE grows large? but is restricted from the inner join?

Comment: It didn't scale that well. but i can work on that. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: I went away from CUBE and simply added another level of aggregation where in your outer select i NULL columns not in my group for that row. That way its easy to aggregate groups where all rows from a certain dimension is needed without the row explosion of CUBE.